# Checking local disk space on opensuse

Tags: linux, ubuntu, storage, opensuse

I want to check the storage usage on my Opensuse system and when I use `df -h`
I get:

```
> Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs               7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                  7.9G  284M  7.6G   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  7.9G  2.5M  7.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                  7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p2          50G   19G   30G  38% /
/dev/nvme0n1p1         156M  4.6M  152M   3% /boot/efi
/dev/nvme0n1p3          70G   51G   19G  73% /home/st04
/dev/sda2              900G   33M  900G   1% /export/scratch
tmpfs                  1.6G   40K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1122
iam:/export/local  179G  141G   39G  79% /mnt/server/local
tmpfs                  1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/481
pop:/export/home       131G   44G   87G  34% /home/pop
nest:/export/home      74G   34G   40G  46% /home/nest
ruhh:/export/home       50G   44G  5.8G  89% /home/ruhh
iam:/export/home   739G  555G  184G  76% /home/iam
yellow:/export/home   50G  7.1G   43G  15% /home/yellow
nata:/export/home      50G  452M   49G   1% /home/nata
```

can you explain what does this message mean? How do I understand what is the local usage stated here?

Comment: See https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-df/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out everything with [grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) which does not begin with */dev* to see your local storage use. Why? Well, you probably wish to filter out irrelevancies such as *tmp*

```
df -h | grep '/dev'
```

[grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) also allows multiple patterns to filter in, if you specify what you want.  You could add patterns to also see your networked file systems as well from the machines iam, pop, nata, nest, ruhh, and yellow, if you wished.

Comment: Thanks @K7AAY. grep is something I should use more often, I realized.

Comment: Should have named is `slick` instead of `grep` because it is slick.

Answer (score 1):

You face multiple problems, coincidentally:

1. Recent Linuxes, around some years ago, started to utilize multiple virtual filesystems to deal with the system. These are the "tmpfs", "devtmps" filesystem types on the beginning.
2. Your SuSE seems to use multiple networked filesystems, attached from other machines. These are effectively network-attached storages for your box, thus they are listen among your mounts.

If you remove them all, only this remains:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p2          50G   19G   30G  38% /
/dev/nvme0n1p1         156M  4.6M  152M   3% /boot/efi
/dev/nvme0n1p3          70G   51G   19G  73% /home/st04
/dev/sda2              900G   33M  900G   1% /export/scratch
```

So you have only 4 partitions, and it is already much more clear.

(1) is hardly critizied even beside the Linux users, although it has many advantages, too. (2) is caused by your SuSE.

K7AAY's simplification in the other answer is a pretty simple and nice one.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, this definitely helps.